# Replace curl with wget for compressed data

Tags: linux, bash, dockerfile, wget

We are using `curl` and we want to change to `wget`.

The `curl` command is like following:

```
curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/v1.22.4/yarn-v$1.22.4.tar.gz" && \ mkdir -p /opt  && \
tar -xzf yarn-v1.22.4 -C /opt/
```

I've tried with `wget`:

```
wget -c "https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/v1.22.4/yarn-v$1.22.4.tar.gz"
```

But not sure regard compressed to get the same effect exactly in `wget`.

Comment: `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wget` has the `--compression=type` option:

```
--compression=type
       Choose the type of compression to be used.  Legal values are auto, gzip and none.
```

For both `curl` and `wget` compression option adds `Accept-Encoding` header to a request. `curl` adds `Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, br` and `wget` adds `Accept-Encoding: gzip`.